# Misuse of [laser] tag?

Tags: discussion

I was looking through tags, and 6 out of [the 8 questions with the [laser] tag](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laser) are about laser printers.  Did we intend to do it this way?  If not, we should add tag guidance, and edit the questions about laser printers to remove the tag.

Answer (score 1):

I've removed the tag from the questions that misused it. If you see things like this where the misuse is fairly clear, you're welcome to submit suggested edits to fix it up; they'll often get dealt with faster than through meta.

Comment: Well, I was trying to make this one tag edit, and it told me that I had to have at least 8 character difference.  The post itself was good.  Was this a bug then?

Comment: No, that's a by-design feature of questionable usefulness that's supposed to prevent "trivial" edits... which also prevents useful small edits like tags. If you can find anything in the post to correct as well, add that to your edit to get around it; if not, find someone who has full editing privileges to make the edit.

Comment: Maybe I should mention, this only happens with questions originated on another site, e.g. https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9285/does-a-device-like-this-exist.  Maybe this **is** a bug?